# Trying to concat two time series dataframes and matchup the timestamps as close as possible

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I concatenate two pandas dataframes with a datetime index, so that the timestamps match up as close as possible. Could there be a padding method to use?

An example could be:

```
#required packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# defining stuff
num_periods_1 = 11
num_periods_2 = 4

# create sample time series
dates1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=num_periods_1, freq='10min')
dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000 00:40:00', periods=num_periods_2, freq='10min')

column_names_1 = ['B', 'C', 'A']
column_names_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_periods_1, len(column_names_1)), index=dates1, columns=column_names_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_periods_2, len(column_names_2)), index=dates2, columns=column_names_2)

print("\nData Frame One:\n", df1)
print("\nData Frame Two:\n", df2)

df3 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index().add_suffix('_x'), df2.reset_index().add_suffix('_y')], axis=1).set_index(['index_x', 'index_y']).sort_index(axis=1)
print("\nData Frame Three:\n", df3)
```

Here the output will appear as the following:

```
                                              A_x       B_x       B_y  \
index_x             index_y                                             
2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 00:40:00  0.878508 -0.608439 -0.468326   
2000-01-01 00:10:00 2000-01-01 00:50:00 -1.056812  0.070073  0.802728   
2000-01-01 00:20:00 2000-01-01 01:00:00 -0.085436  0.577973  1.278077   
2000-01-01 00:30:00 2000-01-01 01:10:00 -0.061046 -0.410809 -1.913346   
2000-01-01 00:40:00 NaT                 -0.522415 -1.128558       NaN   
2000-01-01 00:50:00 NaT                  0.423210  1.266240       NaN   
2000-01-01 01:00:00 NaT                 -2.411029 -0.303869       NaN   
2000-01-01 01:10:00 NaT                  0.050969 -0.807989       NaN   
2000-01-01 01:20:00 NaT                 -0.466958  0.311464       NaN   
2000-01-01 01:30:00 NaT                 -0.137329 -0.234095       NaN   
2000-01-01 01:40:00 NaT                 -1.089133 -0.173481       NaN   

                                              C_x       C_y       D_y  
index_x             index_y                                            
2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 00:40:00  2.298649  0.673585 -1.586648  
2000-01-01 00:10:00 2000-01-01 00:50:00 -1.791427  0.907333  0.950786  
2000-01-01 00:20:00 2000-01-01 01:00:00 -0.980498 -0.625798  0.284694  
2000-01-01 00:30:00 2000-01-01 01:10:00  1.337427 -0.859036 -0.237332  
2000-01-01 00:40:00 NaT                 -1.493857       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 00:50:00 NaT                  0.455737       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 01:00:00 NaT                  0.393388       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 01:10:00 NaT                 -1.612417       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 01:20:00 NaT                  2.471329       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 01:30:00 NaT                 -0.541828       NaN       NaN  
2000-01-01 01:40:00 NaT                 -0.162694       NaN       NaN
```

What I want to have done is shift the second index to where the timestamp matches the first index. Is this possible to do witn concat, join, or merge?

Comment: Maybe do `df2 = df2.reindex_axis(df1.index, 0, method='nearest')` before the concat?

Comment: It depends when it is not exactly matched  which direction you want `pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_on='index_x',right_on='index_y',direction='backward')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would do but if you use reindex before concat,

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index)
df3 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index().add_suffix('_x'),\ 
df2.reset_index().add_suffix('_y')], axis=1)\
.set_index(['index_x', 'index_y']).sort_index(axis=1)
```